# Accessing UserControl when it's a DataTemplate in a ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, datatemplate

Fist time question long time user of Stack Overflow.  I'm somewhat new to the whole MVVM space so I think my Google Fu is failing me. I apologize if I get some of these terms incorrect.

I currently have an observable list class:InstrumentExecutor.

This list is then set as the ItemsSource of a ListBox called InstrumentList.

The ListBox is setup to use a DataTemplate with a FrameworkElementFactory that uses the InstrumentControl UserControl to display the data.

DataTemplate code:

```
    DataTemplate instrumentDataTemplate = new DataTemplate();
    instrumentDataTemplate.DataType = typeof(InstrumentExecutor);
    FrameworkElementFactory frameelement = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(InstrumentControl));
    instrumentDataTemplate.VisualTree = frameelement;
    InstrumentList.ItemTemplate = instrumentDataTemplate;
```

And that is all working just great!  Data is flowing in and out and everyone is happy. Here's the part where I'm having trouble.

In the user control there is some Expander WPF code.  I am wanting to send an event, call a method, do something to trigger the expansion or collapse from the parent ListBox to each and every item in this listbox. Whenever I iterate the InstrumentList.Items the data source (InstrumentExecutor) is the only data I see.

There's some ways I can hack around using properties and notifications in the data class (Instrument Executor) but I'd like to see if I can make it cleaner.

So is there a way I can access each UserControl? I've looked at ItemContainerGenerator but haven't had much luck.

Thanks for the help!

Update 1:  Using the VisualTreeHelper idea and some StackOver during the usercontrol load event for each line item I can find the parent (code below) and build a linkage that way. Here's the code that goes with this idea.

```
public static T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject current) where T : class
{
        DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
        if (parent == null)
            return null;

        if (parent is T)
            return parent as T;
        else
            return FindParent<T>(parent);
}
```

It works but it's not as sexy as I'm used to.  Next up is trying the Binding idea.  Thanks!

Comment: WPF's VisualTreeHelper should be able to help you here.

Comment: Typically using MVVM you bind to a property and then fire on it when it's property changed.  Implementing INotifyProperty changed is a must.  Then typically when something changes you expose a property through a binding in XAML like this: 'IsExpanded="{BInding Expanded}"'.  This property would typically then be 'set' in the ViewModel and then typically trigger another operation.  If you want to set up buttons and such to fire their events you need to then set up a 'DelegateCommand' or similar to inherit from an ICommand.

Comment: I always pimp out Josh Smith's old MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx.  You really want to learn about data binding to truly leverage MVVM.  As you in essence are wanting to expose Views to databind to ViewModels and have them look at things with data and or schema in models.